# Yarn build error exit code 1 metaplex nft marketplace

Tags: yarnpkg, metaplex

I'm trying to make a metaplex marketplace and every time I run `yarn build` I get this

```
Node.js v17.2.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.

lerna ERR! yarn run build exited 1 in 'gumdrop'
lerna WARN complete Waiting for 1 child process to exit. CTRL-C to exit immediately.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have tried flushing the yarn cache, I've tried updating yarn, I've tried the other examples in another Stack Overflow post I've tried so many things and I can't list or remember them all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to downgrade Node? sudo n v16.13.2

Comment: please ask questions in the comments for the question. Please use answer when you are actually answering the question or providing a solution.

Comment: Asked the user not to use answer section to ask follow up  questions

Comment: Yes I switched to Node v16.13.0 and that worked I had the most current version of node running. Thank You!